# P4V not showing edited stream mappings in workspace view

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-stream

This has been a constant frustration when transitioning from git. Sometimes when scoping my stream I import a folder then find that I will need to edit it. So after removing the folder path from my mapping it disappears but when I try to re-add it as a share, the mappings are correct but the folder will not populate in my workspace. I have combed through Perforce terrible documentation to come up with no solution. After I add a mapping what am I missing to get that to populate? I suspect it is not branching the files I have added but don't really know. How can I get the added folders to show up?

**Summary:**
changing `import //dev/root_fld/fld_A` to `share //dev/root_fld/fld_A` in stream mapping updates the workspace but no folder appears.

Comment: From the command line you'd do `p4 populate -r -S myStream fld_A/...` to populate (branch into) the newly mapped folder -- I'm not sure offhand what the P4V equivalent is, or if it's clever enough to do this automatically when you edit the stream spec.  If you do a "merge" operation followed by an auto-resolve I'd expect that to pick up the "new" files along with any other changes from the parent.

Comment: Thinking more about this, I think `merge` is actually the best option, because it ensures that you atomically get the new `share` files along with any other changes.  Doing the `populate` on that directory might leave you with an inconsistent state if there are dependencies between files in those directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a merge from the parent stream.  This will pick up all changes from the parent that aren't yet reflected in the current stream, including the files that exist in the parent but haven't yet been branched.  (Do an "automatic resolve" to automatically accept all the branched files -- when you do a merge you have the option to "ignore" them also but you probably don't want to do that!)

Comment: Thank you Samwise the merge then resolve added all the newly branched files to a CL. Thank you for the help. Wish their docs were more tuned to first time users.